# i am unable to get the text of a locator having multiple text.. can anyone guide me on this

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

I have three texts but i want to get one by one to iterate in for loop

```
FOR    ${iter}     IN RANGE  1   4
        ${tab}=    get text    //div[@id="edit-field-page-mode-display--wrapper--description"]//b[${iter}]
        ${value}=    get text    //*[@id="edit-field-page-mode-display--wrapper--description"]
            Run Keyword If    "tab${iter}" == "${tab}" and "tab${value}_value" == "${value}"
            ...    log   "${tab}" and "${value}" is in current page
END
```

[Screenshot of HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUeyk.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do with the Run Keyword If expressions - especially the one on the right hand side of the "and" as this seems to make it so expression can never be true givn it's saying "tab${value}_value" == "${value}" which is checking ${value} against itself but embedded within additional text

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do string manip on this as all the text is within a div aside from the bold text. The solution I tried was to get all the text and use `Split To Lines` to convert the string to a list and then extract the strings from it within a loop. The run keyword if expression is questionable so I'll focus answer on getting the text.

Here is an example:

```
Extract Text From HTML
  # Get all the text within the element
  ${all_values}    Get Text    //div[@id="edit-field-page-mode-display--wrapper--description"]

  # Split To Lines - will convert the string to a list
  ${values}  Split To Lines  ${all_values}

  # Loop each entry in the values list and do some string manip
  FOR    ${iter}   IN RANGE  1   4
      ${index}  Set Variable  ${iter-1}
    
      # seperate bold text and standard text 
      ${bold_text}  ${standard_text}  ${remainder}  Split String From Right  ${values}[${index}]  "  # Split string with double quotes for marker
      ${bold_text}  Strip String  ${bold_text}  characters=${SPACE}

      Log To Console  BOLD: ${iter} = ${bold_text}
      Log To Console  VALUE: ${iter} = ${standard_text}
  END
```